# Front end file upload returning wrong attachment url

Tags: php, uploads, post-meta, attachments, forms

So I'm making a simple file uploader with wordpress where users don't need to go into wp-admin to add a file.

I have it working great, it uploads the file to the correct folder..etc but the only problem I'm running into is its returning the wrong file url.

For example when uploading a file it goes to **'/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/file.png'** but it returns the attachment URL as **'/uploads/file.png'**

My Code:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-load.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-admin/includes/media.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-admin/includes/file.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-admin/includes/image.php');

if(!$_FILES) exit;
if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

//define variables
if(isset($_FILES['fileUpload'])) {$files = $_FILES['fileUpload'];}
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

$file_name = $files['name'];
$file_vars = array('test_form' => FALSE); //Allows form submission
$file_post = wp_handle_upload($files, $file_vars); //Posts File
$file_link = $file_post['url']; //Full URL
$file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($file_link), null); //File Extension

$post_name = preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file_link)); //Post Name

$attachment = array(
    'guid' => $file_link, 
    'post_mime_type' => $file_type['type'],
    'post_title' => $post_name,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_name);
//Generates meta
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file_name);
//Updates meta
$attach_final = wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `var_dump` your variables and you should see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For `wp_insert_attachment` and `wp_generate_attachment_metadata`,  change `$file_name` in the following way.

```
$file_name = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . basename($file_name);
```

Wordpress codex for both function ( [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata) ) says- ' Use absolute path and not the URI of the file. The file MUST be on the uploads directory'  `$_FILES['fileUpload']` just gives the name of the file , not the absolute path along with.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a little while ago, and without rehashing everything line-by-line to remember how exactly I did what, the one thing that I spot different in my code vs. yours is you have:

```
$file_link = $file_post['url'];
```

whereas I have something like:

```
$file_link = $file_post['file'];
```

See if that makes the difference...